# Flutter: How to navigate to a specific tab in TabBar on button click which is in another screen?

Tags: flutter, navigation, tabbar

I have HomeScreen with two tabs, SecondScreen and a ThirdScreen. I wish to navigate to second tab by clicking on the button located inside the ThirdScreen. How to achieve this?

Navigator.push gets me back to first tab, which is not what I want.

my navigation map in my app is somewhat like this: second tab -> SecondScreen -> ThirdScreen -> HomeScreen. how to go back to the tab i came from , from the third screen.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter navigate to specific tab in other page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58995614/flutter-navigate-to-specific-tab-in-other-page)

Comment: no actually, my navigation map in my app is somewhat like this:
second tab -> SecondScreen -> ThirdScreen -> HomeScreen.

how to go back to the tab i came from , from the third screen.